# I am not able find the status field in the case object --record type?

Tags: administration, case

I am not able find the status field in the case object --record type?

For Eg:
I have record type name "xyz" in case object.in that record type i want to show users only 2 picklist values out of 10 in "status" field?

I approaching like this going to record type "XYZ"but i am not able to find the "Status" field in that record type

Can i know why?.if i want to keep only 2 values out of 10 in that record type? what would be the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually controlled by something called a Support Process. Go to Setup > Customize > Cases > Support Processes, and set up your processes as you like. Each Record Type may use any given support process, and multiple Record Types may each use the same Support Process.